# Tool to mark pages of websites as "read" and view links to "read" pages differently?

Tags: web-browser, bookmark

I consult a lot of online documentation, including [POSIX specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/index.html), many others.

When I visit a page I *often* (not always) read that entire page of the docs that I'm consulting.

It occurred to me that it would be extremely useful to have some record of which pages I've already read in their entirety.

(Of course, if I've studied it *well* enough I would hopefully recognize the material :) , but if I've just consulted snippets and never read the whole thing I might not realize I was missing pieces.  Also, if I had read every subpage in a particular chapter except one, such a record could help me notice that fact and fill in the gap in my knowledge.)

The tool I would like would be:

1. *Extremely* lightweight;
2. Not require extensive permissions (like ability to "read and modify all websites I visit" or similar);
3. Should work with Safari 10.0 on macOS 10.11.6;
4. Should allow me to easily "mark as read" a webpage I am viewing;
5. Should allow me to generate lists of which pages I've read on a particular site;
6. Ideally, should allow me to see on a "table of contents" webpage (such as [this one for part of the Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql.html)) which of the pages I've read and which I haven't.

Does such a tool even exist?